# What's the optimal way to handle a HttpClient on Android?

Tags: android, httpclient

I can find loads of tutorials that show how should a HttpClient constructed and used in a *simple* case. But I fail to find any decent documentation for more complex cases.

In my app, I have a bunch of Activities, and each has to be able to communicate with a remote WebService with POST messages using HTTPS. I also have to log in to this service, so I need to manage the login cookie.

Currently, I construct a separate HttpClient for every single Activity in .onStart(), and releasing it in .onStop(). I have a work-queue that contains the objects describing the details of a task that has to communicate with the remote service. I execute these tasks using a single worker AsyncTask. This solution seems to work, but I'm just not sure that it's the most optimal one.

I've thought about 2 other architectures:

1. Creating a background Service that handles the HttpClient. This way I might be able to use the same instance thru multiple Activities, and I guess this'd be better. But I'm not sure when to stop this Service and release the HttpClient.
2. Create a HttpClient only when needed. So for example when the user clicks a button that initiates a remote call, then I construct the client, set up the cookies and the POST message, execute it, and when it's done I immediately release it. I think this approach is quite bad because of the overhead involved in creating such a client (especially if I use HTTPS).

So anybody that has more insight about the workings of HttpClient and how it should be treated in Android, could you please comment on these approches / share some useful tips?

Thanks

Comment: first off, the http connection should not be related to any activity, but rather to a service

Comment: Have you performance data that indicates the need to optimise HttpClient creation away? Both solutions are good, but remember the KISS principle and whether such changes are actually worth the additional complexity.

Comment: No, I didn't measure this. However, I'm rather interested in a better architecture. Because now it seems that my app is working, but it may be that I'm doing something fundamentally stupid, and there's a much cleaner / better way to do this task. I also think that many other devs have to work with HttpClient in more complex cases, and I haven't found a place where this's discussed thoroughly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

solution 1 is good. You can stop your service once your queue is empty. It combines with your solution 2 in that that the service is started only when needed. When your user clicks a button, you start your service, and for instance you bind to it and give it your request.

Answer (score -2):

Asynctask. Search on Google a method called GrabURl.